# Python: How to make the function run unconditionally when the program ends?

Tags: python, events, exit, atexit

I must ensure that the end_event() function is executed at the end of the program. I tried to implement this as Python's atexit. However, when the .py file was converted to an exe file with a PyInstaller and closed with a click, it did not work. I would appreciate it if you could tell me a solution that always works. Have a good day.

```
import atexit
import signal
import pyupbit

def end_event():
    for keys in buy_list.keys():
        order = upbit.get_order(keys)
        if "state" in order:
            if(order['state'] == 'wait'):
                upbit.cancel_order(keys)
    exit(1)

atexit.register(end_event)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, end_event)
```

Comment: “closed with a click” — that’s effectively a KILL -9 in windows if it passes through the handling to the default OS behavior.

Comment: Then, is there no way to implement it on Python code in this case? (Crying..)

Comment: Package it with a small PyTK wrapper (then you’ll have control over the UI aspect..)?

Comment: Launch a standalone (two-part) process? So when the “client” (ie. sub-process of the windows terminal) dies, the “server” can shutdown cleanly?

Comment: Interesting! I'll try this method, too. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: There are probably existing libraries to help with “robust” Python apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee that code will run when the process exits, because there are ways to exit which do not permit any code to run.

- User may pull the power cable. No code can run because there is no power.
- External events (power outage, lightning strike), same as above.
- Kill -9 or equivalent, e.g. Windows' `TerminateProcess`

### Patterns for emergency cleanup.

The best pattern is: Never be in a state which requires emergency cleanup.

- There is no guarantee that your cleanup will run because you could have a kill -9 or a power outage.
- Therefore you need to be able to recover in that scenario.

See also: [What does the POSIX standard say about thread stacks in atexit() handlers? What's the OS practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655868/what-does-the-posix-standard-say-about-thread-stacks-in-atexit-handlers-what/39871828#39871828)